# Count of NA for ids present in DF1 from source DF2

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi I have two data frames
DF1 and DF2.

DF2 is primarily an attendance keeping system. The columns are IDs, Dates and Amounts

DF1 has IDs and some other columns which are not overlapping.

Now in case an employee is absent the ID and date gets noted down but Amount gets marked as NA (the actual R NA value).

What I'm trying to do is add a column in DF1 which contains count of NAs corresponding to the IDs mentioned in DF1.

The code that I use is as below

```
df1$na_count <- sum(df2$id == df1$id & is.na(df2$amount))
```

I come from an excel background and I believe it should have worked because in the code above I am creating two series of True and False values, wherein the first series we are matching all ids present in df2 to the adjacent id present in df1, and the second series we are independently creating a true or false array for na values. The "And" operator would then create a single True or False array (i.e. if both True, then True else False). The sum of these boolean values would give me the total count.

However it's giving me 0 as the count. Can you help me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: In R use brackets to extract data, something like `df2$id[is.na(df2$amount)]` will return all ID's where df2$amount is equal to NA. If you provide an actual portion of data it would help to arrive at your exact answer

Comment: please share `df1` and `df2`

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the column na_count already exists in df1, try the following:

```
for (i in unique(df1$id) {
  df1[which(df1$id==i), "na_count"] <- sum(is.na(df2$amount[which(df2$id==i)]))
}
```